# How do you do a Fast Fourier Transform in maxima (the computer algebra system)?

Tags: fft, cas, maxima

I get the basic idea of a continuous Fourier transform and I am a little fuzzy with a discrete Fourier transform and hazier still on the fast Fourier transform. I want to know how to compute and interpret the fast Fourier transform (FFT) of some function in maxima. For example, how would I compute the FFT of sin(x)? I know how to do this in MATLAB, but I am not sure how to do it in maxima.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a built-in fast Fourier transform function: see 'fft'.

'fft' is only for numerical data. Maybe you want a function which works for symbolic data as well. It is easy to write an ordinary (not fast) discrete Fourier transform as a summation, something like: `(1/n) sum(y[k]*exp(2*%pi*%i*j*k/n)` for the `j`-th element. (Formula may be wrong, I am working from memory.)

If you want a fast Fourier transform for symbolic data, you will need to work from a published algorithm. (There are many books which have FFT algorithms in them.) Just write the algorithm in Maxima and operations will automatically be symbolic.

Comment: I do not mind using numerical data as that is how I would do it in MATLAB. My problem is that I don't know how to do it numerically in maxima.

Comment: OK, for numerical data, use the 'fft' function in Maxima. Enter '? fft' at the input prompt to get documentation.

Comment: I figured I should update this. I managed to get it to work by using bits and pieces of qfft.mac (not part of standard maxima). I modified it enough to get it to work the way I need. Thanks.